# Testing scoped mass assignment with RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, testing, rspec, mass-assignment

I have a model with the following mass assignment protection defined as:

```
attr_accessible :attachment, :body, :feed_id
attr_accessible :attachment, :body, :feed_id, :approved, :as => :admin
```

The code works as expected in the controller, only allowing `approved` to be mass assigned when called like

```
@post.update_attributes(params[:post], :as => :admin)
```

I usually test mass assignment using shoulda like so:

```
it { should_not allow_mass_assignment_of(:approved) }
```

However, I cannot find a way to test scoped mass assignment, e.g. something like

```
it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:approved, :as => :admin) }
```

(That doesn't work).

Does anyone know how to test this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For Rails > 3.1 try

```
it { should allow_mass_assignment_of(:approved).as(:admin) }
```